# Python2: multiprocessing.dummy.Pool vs multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool

Tags: python, python-2.7, threadpool, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

In python 2, is there any difference between `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` and `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`?  The source code seems to imply they're the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're the same (both on Py2 and Py3); `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` is just a thin wrapper that imports and calls `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`. The actual code is just:

```
def Pool(processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=()):
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    return ThreadPool(processes, initializer, initargs)
```

In general, I'd prefer using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` only because the existence of `multiprocessing.dummy` [is officially documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy), where `multiprocessing.pool` is not (it's an internal implementation detail).

**Update:** As of Python 3.7, [the `multiprocessing.dummy` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) explicitly document the existence of [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool), so if you're *definitely* using threads and will never want to switch, arguably `ThreadPool` is better for being explicit about threads being used. If you might be switching back and forth, it's easier if all you have to do is add and remove `.dummy` from:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool  # And maybe other imports that need to switch for process vs. threads
```

so I'd recommend continuing to use `Pool` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for stating your preference as to which to use.

Comment: What is the difference between using threads and processes, please for multiprocessing.dummy and multiprocessing? So all threads will be under one process? If processes closes execution, then all threads stop?

Comment: @Avv: Multiple processes means bypassing GIL limitations on CPU bound code, and having the ability to hard kill the workers (you can't properly hard kill threads, or at least you shouldn't). Processes also means data isn't shared between parent and worker by default (a mixed blessing; you can't accidentally mutate shared state, but sharing state when you want to becomes more annoying). There's plenty of information about this in the `threading` and `multiprocessing` docs.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Thank you. Can you please recommend a book about this? I am not familiar with the GIL limitations concept.

Comment: @Avv: Basic intro is [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL). Note that much of the docs there are quite old, so some of the info (e.g. that the GIL can degrade performance even when it's not a bottleneck) is out of date to some extent (they [redesigned it in 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#multi-threading) and the new GIL is dramatically better than the info linked there from 2009 indicates).